# keyboard shortcut to jump to cursor

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

What is the keyboard shortcut to jump the editor view back to where my cursor was last placed?

For example I often scroll to the top or bottom of the editor view other parts of the code, and I would like to be able to quickly jump back to the last section I was viewing.

Comment: Well, you can try this trick: whenever you want to back to your cursor where placed, you can press any alphabet and undoing it.
 (for example) press a and undo .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Scroll to Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHYxC.png) looks like what you need.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> on Windows, not set by default on Mac, but can be customized in the Keymap.

If you are not in the editor, you will need to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> first to focus it.

There is also `Navigate` | `Last Edit Location`, but will navigate you to the last place you've edited, not just viewed.